# React-Calendar month view change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-calendar

I am using [React-Calendar](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useAsyncFn.ts) and I am unable to change the month bu clicking the arrows (back/ forward) in the navigation panel, where the month name is displayed. My code:

```
...
  const onActiveStartDateChangeHandler = ({ activeStartDate, value, view }) => {
    console.log("vv:", activeStartDate, value, view);
  };

...
  return (
    <div className="popupFormSelector arrowLft pb-8">
      <h2 className="text-center font-bold mt-7 mb-5">Set a deadline</h2>
      <Delete classes="right-5 top-5" onClickHandler={toggleCalendar} />
      <Calendar
        activeStartDate={teamStartDate}
        calendarType="US"
        defaultView="month"
        maxDetail="month"
        maxDate={endDate}
        minDate={teamStartDate}
        next2Label={null}
        onActiveStartDateChange={onActiveStartDateChangeHandler}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        prev2Label={null}
        selectRange={false}
        showDoubleView={false}
        showFixedNumberOfWeeks={false}
        showNavigation={true}
        showNeighboringMonth={true}
        tileClassName={tileClasses}
        tileDisabled={({ activeStartDate, date, view }) =>
          date < teamStartDate || date > endDate
        }
        value={new Date()}
        view={"month"}
      />
```

From console.log on handler for `onActiveStartDateChange`, I can see that the date is changed in the log, however, the view stays at the current month. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The month view doesn't change because it is tied to the value you provided here:

> activeStartDate={teamStartDate}

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar#calendar), this initiates a "controlled" behavior:

> **activeStartDate** The beginning of a period that shall be displayed. If you wish to use React-Calendar in an uncontrolled way, use defaultActiveStartDate instead.

So either use `defaultActiveStartDate` instead of `activeStartDate` if it matches your use case, or you could simply update the value of `teamStartDate` in the method, like this:

```js
const onActiveStartDateChange = ({activeStartDate}) => teamStartDate = activeStartDate
```